# Save $_POST to $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, post

I need to save complete `$_POST` to `$_SESSION` and after back it to `$_POST`, I find code for this:

```
// 1.save
$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;

// 2.ERROR HERE - its return empty array
var_dump($_SESSION['POST']);

// 3.reload page

// 4.back all data to $_POST
$_POST = $_SESSION['POST'];
```

Of course at the top of file I have `session_start()`; and I use working `$_SESSION` variables in my file without any problems.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe your $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to store all of `$_POST` into the `$_SESSION`, adopt the following;

```
$_SESSION['POST'] = serialize($_POST); #Copy _POST to _SESSION
$_POST = unserialize($_SESSION['POST']); #Copy it back.
```

- Additionally, you could adopt [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and decode accordingly.

Also, [adopt what helion3 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632673/3000179) and check that `_POST` actually has keys/values before you assign it to the `_SESSION`

#### Here's a quick demonstration.

I have a _POST with the following data,

```
Array ( 
 [name] => Frank 
 [animal] => Penguin 
)
```

And I use the script above to copy it to a `_SESSION` making the value;

```
1a:2:{s:4:"name";s:5:"Frank";s:6:"animal";s:7:"Penguin";}
```

I then copy it back to `_POST`, and becomes what it was originally

```
Array ( 
 [name] => Frank 
 [animal] => Penguin 
)
```

### Here's a demonstration script.

```
<?php

session_start();

$_POST = array();
$_POST['name'] = "Frank";
$_POST['animal'] = "Penguin";

$_SESSION['POST'] = serialize($_POST);
print_r($_SESSION['POST']);

unset($_POST); # _POST has been destroyed

//Now rebuild _POST
$_POST = unserialize($_SESSION['POST']);
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Why store POST as a serialized string when the session supports an array/object?

Answer (score 1):

Until we see more code I'll assume you're not checking whether or not `$_POST` contains data. If it's empty (will always be unless there's actual POST data), it's going to reset the $_SESSION every request.

Check that `$_POST` is not empty (there are multiple ways):

`if( !empty($_POST) )` or `if( count($_POST) )` etc